# Using results of a SELECT to pull relevant values from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm parsing a string from a table with the following query.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN jobdata LIKE '%DocFtpPassword%' 
          THEN SUBSTRING(jobdata, 
                         CHARINDEX('DefColId=', jobdata) + 9, 
                         CHARINDEX('|DocFtpPassword=', jobdata) - CHARINDEX('DefColId', jobdata) - 9) 
          ELSE 'No Import Library' 
    END AS 'Import_Library' 
FROM
    jobscompleted
```

What I want to do then is to take each row and pull another value via another table. I know I could just write out the same statement twice, as in,

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN jc.jobdata LIKE '%DocFtpPassword%' 
          THEN SUBSTRING(jc.jobdata, 
                          CHARINDEX('DefColId=', jc.jobdata) + 9, 
                          CHARINDEX('|DocFtpPassword=', jc.jobdata) - CHARINDEX('DefColId', jc.jobdata) - 9) 
          ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'Import_Library', 
    c.collectionname 
FROM   
    jobscompleted jc 
JOIN 
    collection c ON CASE 
                       WHEN jc.jobdata LIKE '%DocFtpPassword%' 
                          THEN SUBSTRING(jc.jobdata, 
                                         CHARINDEX('DefColId=', jc.jobdata) + 9, 
                                         CHARINDEX('|DocFtpPassword=', jc.jobdata) - CHARINDEX('DefColId', jc.jobdata) - 9) 
                          ELSE NULL 
                    END = c.collectionid
```

but that obviously is super redundant.  Is there a way to do this in a much more succinct and readable way, and bear in mind I don't really know anything about stored procedures or variables (although there's always a good time to learn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for. If not, please provide more details to the question.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN jobdata LIKE '%DocFtpPassword%' 
          THEN SUBSTRING(jobdata, 
                         CHARINDEX('DefColId=', jobdata) + 9, 
                         CHARINDEX('|DocFtpPassword=', jobdata) - CHARINDEX('DefColId', jobdata) - 9) 
          ELSE 'No Import Library' 
    END AS 'Import_Library' 
FROM
    jobscompleted ) AS jc
INNER JOIN 
collection c ON jc.Import_Library  = c.collectionid
```

Comment: I feel silly, but your answer makes so much sense. Basically a sub query to build another table, then use the alias to join.  I'll give this a go but the logic is really sound. Thanks for the help,!